# Update string in List

Tags: c#

I have loaded a txt comma delimited into multiple lists. For example

```
static public void File()    
{    
    var order_no = new List<String>();    
    var quantity = new List<String>();    
    order_no.Add(fields[0]);    
    quantity.Add(fields[1]);    
}
```

Now what i am trying to is in a loop while the same order is found down the list and the quantity is null then update the quantity in the previous.

For example

> order NO : 1     quantity: null
>
> order NO : 5     quantity: 2
>
> order no : 1     quantity: 1

what it should do is to update the quantity in the first value to 1.

How can i accomplish that?

Comment: Your question is *extremely* unclear. (Aside from anything else, why are you using two parallel lists instead of introducing an `Order` type with a number and a quantity? And why are you using strings for values which are apparently numbers?)

Comment: Why are you still using List<string>? Do order_no and quantity lists contain strings such as "order NO : 1" or something else?

Comment: Sorry for been so unclear. As im new i was trying to divide each column into different list. I canno use it integer as further down the order no might be for ex. 1A. Same with quantity. Petrina do you recommend some other option than list?. The quantity list might have "1" or "1x2"

Comment: as shown above you should first mybe rethink the concept to a mulit dimentional collection. Something as described here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Collections/UseTwodimensionalarrayC.htm Then the whole updating scenario should go easyer or do you really need pararel lists?

Comment: You should try using a `Dictionary` or use a `List` of type `Order` with order no and quantity as suggested by John Skeet in the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i would prefer a `Dictionary<String, String>` instead since these pairs belong logically together(one quantity per order). But ok...

You could group by order_no and select only one not-null value(if any):

```
var orderGroups = order_no
    .Select((order, index) => new { 
         order, index,
         quantity = quantity.ElementAtOrDefault(index)
     })
    .GroupBy(x => x.order)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
foreach(var og in orderGroups)
{
    var firstNotNull = og.FirstOrDefault(x => x.quantity != null);
    if (firstNotNull != null)
    {
        var allIndices = og.Select(x => x.index);
        foreach (int index in allIndices)
            quantity[index] = firstNotNull.quantity;
    }
}
```

If you don't want the first not-null quantity but the highest one, change these lines:

```
var firstNotNull = og.Where(x => x.quantity != null)
                     .OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.quantity))
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Tim 1 Question. When the file has more than 2 columns what its better to use as dictionary only accepts 2 values( for example a file with 40 Columns)

Comment: @user1805445: If you know how many columns there are, you should create a class with these properties. Then you can use a `List<MyClass>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) for this perpose

```
Dictionary<string, string> orders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
if (orders.ContainsKey(field[0]))
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(orders[field[0]]))
    {
        orders[field[0]] = field[1];
    }
}
else
{
    orders.Add(field[0], field[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone ill give dictionary a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary, if your order numbers are unique:

```
var orders = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// This I assume is your file reading magic
foreach (line in lines)
{
    fields = line.Split(' ');

    if (!orders.ContainsKey(fields[0])
    {
        orders.Add(fields[0], fields[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        orders[fields[0]] = fields[1];
    }
}
```